# Table in Table with custom key name

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have to declare a table in a table that will act like this:

```
table = {'79402d' = {'-5.4','5','1.6'}, '5813g1' = {'3','0.15','18'}}
```

So when I loop through it, I can use something similar to `table['79402d'][0]` to print coordinates.

Comment: Obviously that's not working, cuz of `unexpected symbol near '='`...

Comment: Lua indexing begins at 1.

Comment: Yes, in the syntax of the inner table and with the `ipairs` function, indexing begins at 1. But, in general, any value of any type except `nil` and NaN can be a key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of syntax for table constructors. The general form:

```
t = { ['key'] = value }
```

(If the key is a valid identifier)The syntax sugar form:

```
t = { key = value }
```

Here you are mixing them up. Because `79402d` isn't a valid identifier (beginning with letters or underscore), you have to use the general form:

```
t = {['79402d'] = {'-5.4','5','1.6'}, ['5813g1'] = {'3','0.15','18'}}
```

Comment: That is really what i meant but... Now if i go a bit further, how do i use these 'codes' in a loop? Simple `for a,b in pairs(t) do print(a,b) end` is not working ?

Comment: Obviously i need to check if code is same as name so in a loop i have something like `if name == t[i] then`